# Open Link in New Tab on Button Active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a button on my website that when is active(on click once) adds target `_blank` to a `href` links that has a certain class so they open in a new tab.

This is the code for the button

```
    <li id="toolbar-display">
        <dl>
        <dt>Display</dt>
        <dd id="toolbar-display-newtab" class="first last"><span>New Tab</span></dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
```

Then this is a href link class that I would like to add `_blank` to.

```
    <a class="item-link" href="url">
```

So for this, I use the following javascript which I modified from http://jsfiddle.net/UJMgQ/2/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#toolbar-display-newtab').click(function () {
        if ($(this).toggleClass('active')) {
        $('.item-link').attr('target', '_blank');
        } else {
        $('.item-link').removeAttr('target');
        }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

The code looks like it's correct, but unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm unclear at this point whether it's not detecting the button's active state or its not able to add `_blank`. Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: It seems to be working just fine for me.

Comment: Hmm.. strange it's not working on my site. Does the _blank only get added when the button is pressed on?

Because I thought the button would be considered "Active" after 1 click. Then "Unactive" on another click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of what the toggleClass() returns but based on my test, it does not give you a boolean value that you can use for an if else condition..

Why not try [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to detect if the class active is already set then use toggleClass after detecting it.

I tried recoding your post though I'm not sure if I got your logic right.

```
$(function () {
    $('#toolbar-display-newtab').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.item-link').attr('target', '_blank');
        } else {
            $('.item-link').removeAttr('target');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: well, it seems that the function isn't being called when you click it. Though looking at the generated source code, it looks like that there is a conflicting JQuery issue. I guess you need to apply that too to the code I gave you.

To do so, simply replace all $ with jQuery example: jQuery('#toolbar-display-newtab')

Comment: Here, I'll add a screenshot that better explains what I'm attempting to do. http://i.imgur.com/NpyJH.jpg

Comment: Ah you replied while I replaced my post =) Ok, I changed $(function () to jQuery(function ($) that way I don't have to change all the $.

And it works now =) But the browser doesn't seems to remember the active state on a new tab. The button is still blue, but the links won't open in a new tab until I click on the "New Tab" button again.